# function to getUserInformation not working

Tags: php, html, css

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here, and I'm losing my mind on it.
I'm creating a function adminPanel where you can do various other functions such as getUserInformation from a database. When I call the adminPanel function and input the username in my getUserInformation form it returns "ERROR" from the sql.

Main page index.php

```
<html>
<?php
    include("core/settings.php");
    include("network/databaseConnection.php");
    include("core/headers.php");
    include("core/functions/adminPanel.php");
    $db = connect();

    adminPanel();

?>
</html>
```

adminPanel.php

```
<?php
    include("getUserInformation.php");
    function adminPanel() {
        echo "<p>getUserInformation</p>";
        echo "<form method='POST'>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='user_inputUsername'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='user_inputUsernameSubmit'>";
        echo "</form>";
        $user_inputUsername = $_POST['user_inputUsername'];
        getUserInformation($user_inputUsername);
    }
?>
```

getUserInformation.php

```
<?php
    function getUserInformation($user_inputUsername) {
        global $db;
        $sql = "SELECT " . $user_inputUsername . " FROM userdata WHERE id='$user_id', username='$user_username', password='$user_password', email='$user_email', firstname='$user_firstname', lastname='$user_lastname', phonenumber='$user_phonenumber', address='$user_address', isBanned='$user_isBanned'";
        if(!$result = $db->query($sql)) {die($mysqli->connect_error . " and " . $mysqli->error);}
        $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
        return $data['$user_id'];
    }
?>
```

Also here is my database entry in userdata table
http://prntscr.com/4susj9

Comment: In the `getUserInformation`, where you have `$user_inputUsername` should be the name of the column you want to have returned from your SQL query.  It should be static all of the time (there's no need for a variable here).  As for the rest of the query, it looks like you're trying to populate it with variables that are undefined.  Does `$mysqli->error` tell you anything?

Comment: Replace your commas with `AND` to seperate your `WHERE` clause values. What you're using now, is `UPDATE/SET` syntax.

Comment: i think you have to use AND instead of comma in your WHERE condition .

Comment: $mysqli->error didn't tell me anything, I just get the <p>getUserInformation</p> and the form. Also, so what should I do with the function adminPanel($user_inputUsername) {?

Comment: `WHERE id='$user_id' AND username='$user_username' AND  password='$user_password'` etc. etc. that. ^^^

Comment: I fixed that, but it's still not telling me anything. if the username in the database is username I should be grabbing the $user_inputUsername from userdata right? Does it know which things to grab from? Such as the username or password?

Comment: Plus, if you're using an external file for your form, this won't work `<form method='POST'>` it needs to be `<form method='POST' action='handler.php'>`

Comment: what would be in the handler.php? Would I create the variable from the post and then call the function with the username?

Comment: You seem to have a LOT of missing parts in your code. Variables are coming from where and being defined how? All you have is one form element. `<input type='text' name='user_inputUsername'>` - I can't help you with this, not any further, there's too much work to be done to *hopefully* make it work.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` that will outline errors in your code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the sql query you are using here is not right ..You would need to use `AND` between the where clauses.

It must be like `WHERE id='$user_id' AND username='$user_username'` etc ..

Secondly you would need to link your file with `action` in the form element like

```
<form method='POST' action='handler.php'>
```

as @fred mentioned in the comment.